# How to prevent Office from looking in sharepoint when saving

Tags: office-integration

When one of the users try tries to save a file in Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, ...) a message appears:

> Contacting \servername\DavWWWRoot for information. Press ESC to cancel.

A window then opens on Libraries to save the file.

The problem is that it takes time to contact the server.

I would like to know if it is possible to prevent Office from looking in our sharepoint site when the user saves.

Comment: Will you help me clarify: is the issue that when they go to save anything, the dialog opens to SharePoint (instead of say, a local folder) even if the user wishes to save the document locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wan't to save it in SharePoint you need to check if the site exits, if the file already exists etc. That is - you need to contact the server. The same thing happens when you save locally, but the local file subsystem is way faster than the HTTP protocol, network and SharePoint. This is something you have to live with when using SharePoint.

> "Easy to save or easy to find - you can't have both..."